# Executing a C program from Matlab

Tags: c, matlab

I need to execute a C program through Matlab and I'm using the `system()` function for this purpose.
However, the C program computes a float number and returns it as a string that I save in a Matlab variable. Then I 
convert it to double by means of the `str2double()` function but this is not always working. Sometimes the
`str2double()` returns a NaN even though I get the correct string from the C program.
I attach the code that I wrote in Matlab (*v* and *a* are vectors of the same length that have been previously computed):

```
for i=1:length(v)
    fun = './compute_power';
    arg1 = ' 0';
    arg2 = num2str(v(i));
    arg3 = num2str(a(i));
    arg4 = ' 250';

    execution_path = strcat(fun, arg1, {' '}, arg2, {' '}, arg3, arg4);
    execution_path = char(execution_path);

    [status, result] = system(execution_path);

    power(i) = str2double(result);
end
```

I can't figure out the mistake because sometimes it works well and sometimes not.
Is there another way to get the same result without using the `str2double()`?

Comment: Try printing out the `result` string to see what kind of surprising non-numeric value it sometimes contains.

Comment: I found out that the `result` string sometimes contains a 0x0 empty char array and, the next iteration it contains two strings. If I execute the code again, the 0x0 empty char appears somewhere else.